# want to pass parameter values in javascript in yii framework

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii2, yii-components

In Yii framework using html elements for displaying contents. In that want to pass the (`$i`) values on the `onchange` method and calculation done in script. Only the first value is coming always on `onchange` method. Want to get current value of (`$i`) which is looping in `foreach` loop.

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($sub_marks as $sub) { $i++?>

  <td>
    <?= Html::textInput('reg_cia'.$i,"",['id'=>'reg_cia','style'=>'width:40px']); ?>
  </td>
  <td>

    // Here the onchange method only first value is passing always 
    <?= Html::textInput('reg_ese'.$i,$i,['id'=>'reg_ese','tabindex'=>'1','style'=>'width:40px','onchange'=>'js:alerts()'])?>\

  </td>
  <td>
    <?= Html::textInput('reg_total'.$i,"",['id'=>'reg_total','style'=>'width:40px']); ?>
  </td>

  </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<script>
  function alerts()
  {
    var a="reg_cia";
    var b="reg_ese";
    var s=document.getElementById(a).value;
    var g=document.getElementById(b).value;
    alert(s+g);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: because you give same id for all text input, give unique ids to text input

Comment: ya i have given unique id in all see the code and in javascript method i have passed the id value (this.id) and in script i have matched only number and get the id value.  But its not an efficient method i think is there any alternative method for this

Comment: do you know jquery,so i can help you

Comment: yes partially i know

Comment: Layout changes to make reading the code easier.